# PrintWriter doesn't seem to be writing to file even though I'm closing it

Tags: ioexception, printwriter

I'm trying to use `PrintWriter` to print into a predetermined `.txt` file called `output.txt`.
I've not tried putting both File and `FileWriter` inside `PrintWriter`, and having no luck. I'm closing it too. Weirdest part of it is that another similar use of `PrintWriter` in my other code seems to be working perfectly fine (the 2nd one).
Could someone flick me some pointers/hints please?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    if(args.length <4){
        return;
    }else{
        String patternFileN = args[0];
        String sequenceFileN = args[1];
        int numOfSeqs = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        int pattInd = Integer.parseInt(args[3]);
        if(numOfSeqs <= 0){
            return;
        }
        String pattern;
        String[] txtSequence = new String[numOfSeqs];
        PrintWriter outFile = null;
        try{

            String outFileN = "output.txt";
            outFile = new PrintWriter(new File(outFileN));

            for(int seqInd = 0; seqInd < numOfSeqs; seqInd++){
                int offset = RKscanner.seqSearch(txtSequence[seqInd]);
                if(offset < txtSequence[seqInd].length()){
                    //outFile.println(pattInd + " " + seqInd);
                    outFile.println("nigaaaa");

                }
            }
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println("files couldn't be opened");
        }finally{
            outFile.close();
        }

    }
}
```

This code is working fine:

```
public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException{
    int letters = 4;
    int pattLength, possNum; //number of possible sequences

    try{
        if(args.length <=1){
            System.err.println("please specify output filename & lengths of patterns to be generated");
            System.err.println("---try: java patternGen pattern.txt 5");
        }else{  
            String fileName = args[0];
            PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(fileName));
            pattLength = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            possNum = (int)Math.pow(letters, pattLength); //possible number of combinations without wildcards.
            //Nucleotide[][] patternBuild = new Nucleotide[possNum][pattLength];//the built pattern to be used for consructor.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(pattLength);
            for(int i = 0; i < possNum; i++){
                sb.setLength(0);
                StringBuilder alphToNuc = new StringBuilder(0);
                String sbStore = sb.toString();
                //...then string builders populated
                //System.out.println("alphabet: "+sb);
                outFile.println(alphToNuc);
                System.out.println(alphToNuc);
            }
            outFile.close();    
        }

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED!

The problem was that I was running these java files with a bash script in a loop, so the file would overwrite When I open and wrote into these files in the java files.

Sorry for irrelevantly topiced question